How to passthrough a filestream in nestjs without a physical file?
I want to passthrough a file upload in nestjs. Currently the only solution I was able to do was to create a physical file and then read from that:
export type RequestHeaders = {
  'content-type': string;
  'content-length': number;
};

document.controller.ts:
import { Request } from 'express';

@Post()
postFile(@Headers() headers: RequestHeaders, @Req() req: Request) {
  const path = 'qwer';
  req.pipe(createWriteStream(path));
  const stream = createReadStream(path);

  return this.documentService.addFile(headers, stream);
}

document.service.ts
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';

constructor(
  private readonly http: HttpService
){}

post(
  reqHeaders: RequestHeaders,
  body: ReadStream
) {
  return this.http
    .post(
      encodeURI('myUrl'),
      body,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': reqHeaders['content-type'],
          'Content-Length': reqHeaders['content-length'],
        },
      }
    );
}

There has to be a better way than this to create a stream from an incoming request, right?
